# Hierarchical RBAC implementation in PHP?

Tags: php, acl, rbac

What would you suggest? I checked out NIST RBAC PHP API 0.65 but it does not seem to support hierarchy.

In essence I want to have users with sub-users and the sub-users would have roles and access only to what their parent can access. Which seems like a good fit for a hierarchical RBAC scheme.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the trail is cold, but a new project has popped up :

PHP-RBAC is a PHP Hierarchical NIST Level 2 Standard Role Based Access Control and is pretty mature. It is also an OWASP project.

I hope you enjoy it at http://phprbac.net

There were no hierarchical RBAC standard implementations until this one.

Comment: have u personally use it? last time i used zend acl and it quite pita

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using a framework that includes an RBAC? (that has hierarchy). 
First, if you don't, and if you don't have a framework of choice already, then I strongly recommend you go a step back, research, and choose such a framework. I see very little point in developing PHP based apps from scratch. Even very small and target oriented apps could use some parts of a framework.

I use [Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/). This is an extremely light, powerful and performance-oriented framework that fits almost any job you'll need, especially since its so light (everything there is lazy loaded so if use only selected components/features of it, the performance footprint of it is probably un-felt). 
Yii has a good built in RBAC implementation that has your hierarchy requirement.
I advice you have a look at it. [Here's](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control) the relevant section of the official Yii guide, on RBAC and access control.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. The framework to be used is set in stone, so this is not an option.

Comment: and what is it?... don't leave us in the dark! :)

Comment: Nothing exciting, just an internal "company-brew" framework, that 's why didn't mention it :) More of a compilation of classes rather than a full-stack framework such as Yii or Symfony etc.

Comment: I've seen such cases of 'home brew' frameworks. Not a pretty sight, if you'd ask me: there's no freakin' chance that such FWs can match any of the leading PHP framework in virtually all aspects: capabilities/features, bugs. The only reason this habit lives on, sadly and unfortunately (yet understand-ably), is the unwillingness of the companies to invest the temporary resources in moving the dev team forward, to a popular open source framework. Well, I guess that's a matter of a different discussion so I'll quit here :)